# Suddenly getting 404 error for embedded .woff font files

Tags: css

I am getting 404 errors in IIS7 for embedded `.woff` font files. Earlier it was working fine but suddenly it stopped on local as well production site. I tried changing MIME type but nothing works.

Comment: You said you tried changing the MIME type. What did you try? I believe the appropriate woff MIME type should be `application/x-font-woff`

Answer (score 0):

Try this reference link,
[Serving web sites with embedded fonts](https://www.orderfactory.com/articles/Embedded-Fonts/IIS-MIME-types.html)